# How can I disable the notifications shown at bottom right corner in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

The notification window at bottom right corner is pesky. Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: There is no option to disable it.

Comment: Reset Layout, It will be Hide Automatically....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Changing the value in **Query info notifier timeout** to `-1` it will disable it. This is documented in the official pgAdmin documentation in the [Preferences Dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/preferences.html) help as:

> Use the *Query info notifier timeout* field to control the behaviour of the notifier that is displayed when query execution completes. A value of *-1* will disable the notifier, and a value of 0 will display it until clicked. If a positive value above zero is specified, the notifier will be displayed for the specified number of seconds. The default is *5*.

Answer (score 0):

In pgAdmin 4 version 6.19 it's a little bit different, you should go to the Preferences menu, "Query Tool"->"Display", then switch off `Show query success notification?`:

[image: Preferences dialog box of pgAdmin4]

Comment: I'm happy to show it. I'd like way to mark them all as read, as they accumulate.